# Python Tkinter and GUI

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a program/window that has one action button.  This button when clicked, should open a second program/window and close the previous first program.  This second program should have an action button that will open the first and close the second.

I found this script from another user and it works the same way I want the code to run. However, the root window is just being hidden with the deconify() when the otherframe is created.

What would be the best way to destroy the root window when the otherframe is created and still be able to be looped back.

Hopefully this made sense and thanks in advance.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

########################################################################
class OtherFrame(Tk.Toplevel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        Tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.geometry("100x100")
        self.title("otherFrame")

    ########################################################################
    class MyApp(object):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        btn = Tk.Button(self.frame, text="Open Frame", command=self.openFrame)
        btn.pack()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def hide(self):
        """"""
        self.root.withdraw()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def openFrame(self):
        """"""
        self.hide()
        subFrame = OtherFrame()
        handler = lambda: self.onCloseOtherFrame(subFrame)
        btn = Tk.Button(subFrame, text="Close", command=handler)
        btn.pack()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onCloseOtherFrame(self, otherFrame):
        """"""
        otherFrame.destroy()
        self.show()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def show(self):
        """"""
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You want to destroy it and yet be able to go back to it? Do you know what it means to destroy something?

Comment: Why do you need to create two windows? Create a single class to create windows..

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way to destroy the root window and then get it back. There is only one way to destroy it, which is to call the `destroy()` method. When you do that, all children windows will be destroyed and `mainloop` will exit.

While it's possible to destroy and recreate a root window, that's not how tkinter is designed to work, and it will not behave the way you expect it to behave. For example, all instances of `StringVar`, etc. will be destroyed. For another, you must have a root window, so by destroying the root window you will destroy all of its children including the `Toplevel`.

By far, the most common scenario is to simply hide the root window. If you truly want to destroy each window, put nothing in the root window and just leave it hidden. You can then use instances of `Toplevel`, which you can easily destroy and recreate at will.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer... YOU CANT DO IT. The script that you have already is the best bet.

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tkinter
class abc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        tkinter.Button(self.root, text="Click Me", command=lambda:abc.com(self)).pack()
    def com(self):
        self.root.destroy()
        some = abc()

q = abc()
```

This doesn't actually jump between the two but creates a new one every time.